# Flutter 403 error http GETX and HTTP library

Tags: php, flutter, dart, http, flutter-getx

Hello friends I'm coding an web app.
I'm using a PHP web server and HTTP library for response. But I'm getting error when I response. I print the response.statuscode in vs code and it shows me 403 error.
How can I solve this problem.
this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
            import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            import 'package:get/get.dart';
            import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
            import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
            import 'dart:convert';
            import 'dart:typed_data';
            import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

            // Bu alan benim soru değişkenlerimi Getx yardımı ile tuttuğum classdır.farkllı değişken classları yazılabilir.
            class activityController extends GetxController {
              //5 benim değikenimin ilk değeridir.
              var _activityName = "a".obs;
              var _activityDetails = "a".obs;
              var _activityPhoto = "a".obs;

              //get ile çeker, set ile veriyi atarım.
              get activityName => _activityName.value;
              set activityName(yeniDeger) => _activityName.value = yeniDeger;

              get activityDetails => _activityDetails.value;
              set activityDetails(yeniDeger) => _activityDetails.value = yeniDeger;

              get activityPhoto => _activityPhoto.value;
              set activityPhoto(yeniDeger) => _activityPhoto.value = yeniDeger;
            }

            void main() => runApp(MyApp());

            class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
              activityController _controller2 = Get.put(activityController());

              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return MaterialApp(
                  title: 'Material App',
                  home: Scaffold(
                    body: SafeArea(
                        child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          onChanged: (Value1) {
                            _controller2.activityName = Value1;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'activityName'),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          onChanged: (Value1) {
                            _controller2.activityDetails = Value1;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'activityDetails'),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              print("aSF");

                              FilePickerResult? result =
                                  await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                                type: FileType.image,
                              );
                              if (result != null) {
                                Uint8List? file = result.files.first.bytes!;
                                final baseCodeA = base64Encode(file);
                                //do what you want with baseCodeA.
                                _controller2.activityPhoto = baseCodeA;
                                Clipboard.setData(
                                    ClipboardData(text: _controller2.activityPhoto));
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text("FOTO EKLE")),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            final uriAA =
                                'https://www.meshcurrent.online/myWebApp/add_activity.php';
                            var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                            map['activityName'] = _controller2.activityName;
                            map['activityDetails'] = _controller2.activityDetails;
                            map['activityPhotoBase64'] = _controller2.activityPhoto;

                            http.Response response = await http.post(
                              Uri.parse(uriAA),
                              body: map,
                            );
                              print(response.statusCode);
                          },
                          child: Text('ETKİNLİĞİ EKLE'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
```

target of this code is adding some varible to database using http response

Answer (score 0):

You must send a post request with jsonEncoded body. So you can change the parameters of post method

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(uriAA),
  body: map,
);
```

to

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(uriAA),
  body: json.encode(map),
);
```

Of course, you should **import 'dart:convert'** to the file.

Comment: Thanks It's working but I don't understand why It is not working when I use only "body :map".  I think so because It is working my other response without encoded . I was decoding in the PHP server codes. Is It because of BASE64 code? Thanks for your replies